# Crash when switching between users and tags in the Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open the app.
2. Choose any site.
3. Click the site name and choose "users."
4. Click the site name and choose "tags."
5. Click the site name and choose "users" again.
6. Observe crash.

I'm using a Galaxy S4 with Android 4.3.

Comment: Repeated on 4.1.2, RAZR MAXX.

Comment: Repoed on Nexus 7, 4.4.2.

Comment: Thats a weird-assed bug!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was a weird freaking bug. My first reaction was "Huh that's neat, I wonder why that happens", then I realized it's my job to actually figure out the answer to that... Fixed in version 0.1.81 coming out around midnight UTC.

In case anyone is wondering about the "why" like I was, it turns out the android support library's [version of FragmentTransacation.replace() is broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250580/fragment-already-added-illegalstateexception) and has been since 2011, due to (seemingly) a copy-paste typo.